# SOQL Query returning Look up value ID and not name value

Tags: soql

I have written a SOQL query that selects a look up field from a custom object.
My problem is it returns the uuid ( e.g. 1017800012NQqABAFD) and not the name (e.g.Joe Soap).

---

```
Select Name, Surname from Account
```

My result:

```
NAME
1545154151541SADDEEFF 

SURNAME
1655466464648SDEDEFE
```

Why do I get the data in this way? How can I get the data I am looking for instead?

Comment: Can you specify your exact problem so that the community members can assist you in solving your problem. In your question, you said you are querying on Custom Object whereas you queried on `Account` object. If you select a lookup from SOQL, it will always return the Id, to get other fields, you will have to use `__r` in your SOQL. SideNote : Values returned are not Salesforce Ids

Comment: Your title is quite misleading and you added many tags which have nothing to do with your question. I fixed the latter for you, but you or someone else may still wish to take a pass at the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship fields (lookup, master-detail) in the Salesforce UI display the `Name` field of the related record, but that's only due to UI magic.

In the backing data store, lookup fields are actually record Ids (as you are seeing).

If you want to get the name of a related record, you'll need to query for it.

```
List<Opportunity> oppsList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name FROM Opportunity LIMIT 5];

for(Opportunity opp :oppsList){
    system.debug(opp.AccountId); // Will print something like "001000000000123AAA"
    system.debug(opp.Account.Name); // Will print something like "Phil's Chairsmithery"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return of the Id for the Name is usually caused by creating the object without specifying a Name field value - Salesforce ensures that a name is always set, using the Id allocated when needed.

Comment: Is it even possible to create an account with empty name?

Comment: Well, if you read the (rather confusing and inconsistent) question, the implication was that the example SOQL query was only an example but that the real query was operating against a custom object (i.e. not Account as shown).